# 'Throw' in SQL Server 2016 Management Studio - Version 13.0.15000.23

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Has anyone else had a problem with 'Throw'?

If I run the following code, it works as expected:

```
begin try
DECLARE @i int;
SET @i=1/0;
end try
begin catch
print ERROR_NUMBER();
print ERROR_MESSAGE();
end catch
```

It executes fine. If I modify to use a throw:

```
begin try
DECLARE @i int;
SET @i=1;
throw 51000,'Error',1;
end try
begin catch
print ERROR_NUMBER();
print ERROR_MESSAGE();
end catch
```

I get :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'throw'.
```

Note that the keyword ('Throw') lights up in the usual pretty blue, implying that it is recognised, but that's as far as it gets.

I have tried a number of variations and cut/pasted examples from others, but to no avail.

I know there is an SQL Management Studio upgrade, but I am avoiding it for the time being. Last time I tried it, it took me the rest of the day rolling it back because it didn't work (quite spectacularly too).

Thanks

Roger

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are pointing to

Comment: The syntax error is returned by SQL Server, not SSMS.  It seems you are running the script against an older SQL Server version. `THROW` was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I tested this in 2008R2 and then on 2012,your query worked fine in 2012.As Dan pointed out in comments,this is not a SSMS issue,this is a syntax issue

Comment: I tested this code and throw works fine in 2016 and 2014 using compatibility mode. Looks like throw is from 2012 version only https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. It's Sql Server MS 2016 .. this is why I don't really know why it's failing. I may re-install the whole thing though it was installed from scratch (not an upgrade) only 6 months ago.

Comment: What's the compatibility level of the database you're working in? Does it still fail if you `use master` first? What does `SELECT @@VERSION` give?

Answer (score 0):

Doh! .. The database server I am connecting to is 2008 even though my local copy is 2016 .. Thanks for those who commented and put me on the right path